# How do I specify which version of python I want to use with make?

Tags: python, unix, path, makefile

How do I specify which version of python I want to use with make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically `python` is the name of the system's default Python version, but all installed versions are also available with names like `python2.7` or `python3.2`.  You can use those names in a command in a Makefile, or you can put them on the `#!` line of a Python script if you want to invoke it that way.

Answer (score 1):

A makefile just calls a command, you can check what python version is using calling `whereis python` (on UNIX) or checking the PATH environment (Windows). To override the default python you can make the call with the absolute path... just guessing anyway.